# Java - boolean within a week

Tags: java

I am building an application that needs to obtain a list of users that have a dueDate (to fill in a form) this month -- and then filter these users to those that have a dueDate within a week.

so

```
if(isWithinAWeek(dueData)){
 //alarm - 1
}
else{
 //alarm - 0
}
```

--- I need help ensuring this boolean isWithinAWeek method correct

```
public static Boolean isWithinAWeek(Date date1){
    Date c1 = setTimeInDays(date1, 7);      
    if(c1.after(date1)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public static Date setTimeInDays(Date startingTime, Integer days){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(startingTime); 
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);//a day in the future or past
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: The best way to check if your code is correct is to either write unit test cases and/or pass different values to it and check. If things don't work as expected, then please let us know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional as you wrote it will always be true.
It's easier to see if I simplify it:

```
public static boolean isWithinAWeek(Date date) {
    return setTimeInDays(date, 7).after(date);
}
```

This is equivalent to yours, just shorter.
And as you can see, it's effectively saying "return true if date + 7 days is after date".
Which is always true.

You want to check if *now + 7 days* is after `date`,
not `date` + 7 days:

```
public static boolean isWithinAWeek(Date date) {
    return setTimeInDays(new Date(), 7).after(date);
}
```

I also changed the return type from `Boolean` to `boolean`,
because the value will never be null.
And I would recommend to rename `setTimeInDays` to `plusDays`,
as that will resemble the modern date API in recent versions of Java
(so that by the time you learn it, it will look familiar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) to calculate this pretty easily. Here's an example:

```
public static boolean isWithinAWeek(LocalDate dueDate) {
    boolean result = false;
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("Today is " + today);
    System.out.println("Due Date is " + dueDate);

    Period p = Period.between(today, dueDate);

    System.out.println("The period between these two is " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths()  +" months, " + p.getDays() + " days." );

    // do you want to measure a week backwards? If so, change "p.getDays() >= 0" to "p.getDays() >= -7"
    if (p.getYears() == 0 && p.getMonths() == 0 && p.getDays() >= 0 && p.getDays() <= 7) {
        System.out.println(String.format("  └─ Yes, %1$s is within a week from %2$s.", dueDate, today));
        result = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(String.format("  └─ No, %1$s is NOT within a week from %2$s.", dueDate, today));
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Calling this in the following manner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDate due;

    // 7 days from now
    due = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.OCTOBER, 15);
    System.out.println(isWithinAWeek(due));

    System.out.println();

    // 8 days from now
    due = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.OCTOBER, 16);
    System.out.println(isWithinAWeek(due));

    System.out.println();

    // a month from now
    due = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 8);
    System.out.println(isWithinAWeek(due));

    System.out.println();

    // 5 days ago
    due = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.OCTOBER, 3);
    System.out.println(isWithinAWeek(due));

}
```

Will yield the following:

```
Today is 2017-10-08
Due Date is 2017-10-15
The period between these two is 0 years, 0 months, 7 days.
  └─ Yes, 2017-10-15 is within a week from 2017-10-08.
true

Today is 2017-10-08
Due Date is 2017-10-16
The period between these two is 0 years, 0 months, 8 days.
  └─ No, 2017-10-16 is NOT within a week from 2017-10-08.
false

Today is 2017-10-08
Due Date is 2017-11-08
The period between these two is 0 years, 1 months, 0 days.
  └─ No, 2017-11-08 is NOT within a week from 2017-10-08.
false

Today is 2017-10-08
Due Date is 2017-10-03
The period between these two is 0 years, 0 months, -5 days.
  └─ No, 2017-10-03 is NOT within a week from 2017-10-08.
false
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the industry-leading java.time classes.

If interfacing with other code giving a `java.util.Date`, convert to a `Instant` using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

For date-only values, use the `LocalDate` classes.

Your code was ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. If you do not specify otherwise, Java uses your JVM’s current default time zone implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Extract a date-only value, assigning a time zone to determine that date. Keep in mind that for any given moment, the time-of-day and the date vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
LocalDate target = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Get today’s date, and next week and next month.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate nextWeek = today.plusDays( 7 ) ;
LocalDate nextMonth = today.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Compare.

```
Boolean isInNextWeek = ( ! target.isBefore( today ) ) && target.isBefore( nextWeek ) ;
Boolean isInNextMonth = ( ! target.isBefore( today ) ) && target.isBefore( nextMonth ) ;
```